# Windows 10 - Clone Drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, clone

I bought my son a reconditioned PC a couple of years ago.

Now that he's moved on I have inherited the PC and I am puzzled about something. The following drives are displayed:-

Local Disk (C:)
646 GB free of 930 GB

clone of (D:)
76.1 MB free of 509 MB

When I open the D drive there is nothing displayed. What is this drive? I suspected it was an image of the OS as I'm sure there were no OS disks provided with the PC but with nothing visible I don't know for sure what is. If it is indeed an OS image how would I access it?

Comment: “What is this drive?” - It’s a partition on the drive that has erroneously been assigned a drive letter. You can safely remove the drive letter